# Upgrading to Rails 5.0 - updating gem file / gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an existing application which I'm looking to update from rails 4.2.5 to Rails 5.0 (not doing 5.1 yet) and ruby 2.3.0 to 2.4.0. I'm trying to update the gemfile but hitting a number of dependency issues which I believe relates to my gemfile.lock. This is a snapshot from my command line -
[image]

This is my gemfile -

```
     source 'https://rubygems.org'

     ruby '2.4.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.1'
gem 'railties', '~> 5.0'
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.0.1', '>= 5.0.1'
gem 'rails-dom-testing', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
# for styling - not happy but best for grid usage I need (I hope!!)

gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
# for building form templates on the site

gem 'devise', '~> 4.0'
# for creating sign-in / sign-up process

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.2'
# for using images on the site

gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'
# Adding Datepicker

gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 0.2.1'
# to fix problems with turbolinks

gem 'stripe', '~> 1.38'
# for payments / bookings

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth-twitter', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 3.0'
# social logins

gem 'money-rails'
# add money feature

gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.7'
# for google maps / locations

gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.42.0'
# for code styling / errors

gem 'counter_culture', '~> 0.1.33'
# for counting bookings and quantity




# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

My Gemfile.lock file contains versions from previous updates. I'm seeing mixed messages about whether to simply delete this file or not as it appears to only open other cans of worms if I do delete it. Should I simply delete any reference on the gemfile to 'versions'? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please copy+paste the text rather than embedding an image here? It makes the post much easier to read.

Comment: Are you still able to see after working with such screen colors? Like I mean it, did you not lost your vision? It's impossible to look at the picture for longer that zero seconds. Take care of your eyes :)

Comment: Your comments are noted. I was messing around with the colours recently and haven't got round to changing back. I will do as and when i solve this issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to delete the gemfile.lock; if you perform a `bundle update` command; it will try & install from the gemfile.

Comment: Just reading the error message, `sass-rails` is clearly the blocker. What happen when you try to update it?

Comment: I've taken away any version reference but still get the error message above. I can't delete it because I need it. Am I allowed to edit the gemfile.lock file?

Comment: What happens if you **update** `sass-rails`? `bundle update sass-rails`? (You should almost never edit `Gemfile.lock` manually.)

Comment: It says bundle currently locked at rails 4.2.5 and suggests doing bundle update rails which is what I have been doing.

Comment: how about remove Gemfile.lock entirely and run bundle install again

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but have read a few things where it can create more problems than it solves but looks like its the best (only?) option at the minute. Are you using Rails 5?

Comment: just do it, see what happens - i don't imagine it will cause any issues and if it does you can always revert back mate

Comment: Worked. Cheers, dude - hope you're well. Put it as an answer and I'll upvote it:)

Comment: "Remove the Gemfile.lock" is not normally the right answer. The correct answer is "Don't manually edit the Gemfile.lock in the first place, digging yourself into a dependency mess where the only way out is to give up and delete the file"! ;)

Comment: @TomLord agreed but needs must lol

Comment: ...And on a more serious note, my suggestion would have been to *revert* the `Gemfile.lock` to a previous, working state and then re-start the update process properly. On a larger rails project, deleting the file could have gotten you into an even deeper hole.

Comment: But it was working before I tried to update to Rails 5. I hadn't actually touched the gemfile.lock file I just suggested that above as a possible solution.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

how about remove Gemfile.lock entirely and run bundle install again ;) haha

Answer (score 0):

Just run :

```
bundle update
```

and it will update your Gemfile.lock